# Translate JavaScript for loop into Java and simplify it

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to translate the below JavaScript for loop into Java for loop.
What it does is when preferenceType is 'Y_N' then change preferenceValue from 'Y' to true and 'N' to false.

```js
var array = [
  { preferenceCode: 'A1', preferenceType: 'Y_N', preferenceValue: 'Y' },
  { preferenceCode: 'A2', preferenceType: 'Y_N', preferenceValue: 'N' },
  { preferenceCode: 'A3', preferenceType: 'DATE', preferenceValue: '15/03/2018' },
  { preferenceCode: 'A4', preferenceType: 'Y_N', preferenceValue: 'Y' }
];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if(array[i].preferenceType === 'Y_N') {
      array[i].preferenceValue = (array[i].preferenceValue === 'Y');
   }
}

console.log(array);
```

I gave it a go but my Java for loop looks massive and over-complicated (at least the cp.setPreferenceValue bit). Is there a way to simplify it?

```
CompanyPreference[] companyPreferences = returnedPreferencesFromDatabase;           

for(CompanyPreference cp : companyPreferences) {
   if(cp.getPreferenceType().equals("Y_N")) {
      if(cp.getPreferenceValue().equals("Y")) {
         cp.setPreferenceValue(true);
      } else {
         cp.setPreferenceValue(false);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: it is not complicated, it is simple. If it is complicated try to code more.

Comment: You can replace your entire inner if statment with `cp.setPreferenceValue(cp.getPreferenceValue().equals("Y"));`

Comment: @Nick Parsons, Thanks, that's what I've been looking for! Tim ggwp, well, I was sure it could be simplified, that's what the question is all about isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
cp.setPreferenceValue(cp.getPreferenceValue().equals("Y"));
```

similarly to JS. If preference value needs a string, you could convert the boolean to string like this:

```
String.valueOf(cp.getPreferenceValue().equals("Y"))
```

moreover, to make `.equals` comparison null-safe (`getPreferenceValue()` could return null), you probably should go

```
"Y".equals(cp.getPreferenceValue())
```

which will return false in case previous `preferenceValue` is null.

so all in all

```
cp.setPreferenceValue(String.valueOf("Y".equals(cp.getPreferenceValue())));
```

Comment: What would be a good approach in this case if preferenceValue is of type String and doesn't accept Booleans in setPreferenceValue? I can't just change the type to Boolean because preferenceValue also needs to hold Strings in case preferenceType is not 'Y_N'.

Comment: Will that return String "true"?

Comment: yes, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(boolean)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code to following

```
for(CompanyPreference cp : companyPreferences) {
   if(cp.getPreferenceType().equals("Y_N")) {
      cp.setPreferenceValue(cp.getPreferenceValue().equals("Y"));
   }
}
```